# How to transfer IQ tokens on the EOS network?

Tags: cleos

What is the cleos command to transfer tokens other than EOS tokens.  I am trying to use the CLI to transfer IQ tokens from one account to the other.  I can get the balance of the account with:

cleos get currency balance everipediaiq "account name"

However, I cannot get the system to allow a transfer of the IQ tokens between my accounts.

Comment: Are you making your own tokens , or while creating tokens using cleos you just give a random name to your symbol string ?

Answer (score 2):

Use following command:

> cleos push action everipediaiq transfer '["from_account", "to_account", "50.0000 IQ", "Memo ..."]' -p from_account@active